# Python: print json.dumps returns nothing when called standalone

Tags: php, python, json

I'm executing python through PHP, to get some physical properties of fluid.

At the end of python code, I expect to print result as json.

```
result = {
  "Density": Density, 
  "Vis": Viscosity,
  "Cv": Cvcalc,
  "Cp": Cpcalc,
  "kTh":thermalConductivity
}
print json.dumps(result)
```

Above code returns nothing.
As I added the other print(last line), it worked.

```
result = {
  ...
}
print json.dumps(result)
print 's'
```

This is result. I can remove that additional character, but I wonder what is the reason.

```
__output:
   '{
       "Vis": 24.32561332022869, 
       "Cp": 0.9243864539174277,
       "kTh": 0.03403661793540763, 
       "Cv": 0.8251806533784246, 
       "Density": 6.489637890634001
    }\ns\n'
```

**EDIT**
Problem to me was executing absolute path in Bash.
PHP code was like below, and by replacing it to relative path, it is cleared. So, it related to calling code, yes! But is there any meaningful difference between relative vs absolute in file path?

```
shell_exec('python C:\Python27\index.py ' . $fluid . " " . $press . " " . $tempK);
```

```
shell_exec('python index.py' . $fluid . " " . $press . " " . $tempK);
```

Comment: This seems more like a problem with the calling code. You should include it as well.

Answer (score 0):

if you use python3
try:`print(json.dumps(result), flush=True)`

if you use python2
try:

`import sys
 sys.stdout.flush()`

you can refer to:
https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#print

Use file.flush() to ensure, for instance, immediate appearance on a screen